# Flask returns duplicate lists

Tags: python, flask, duplicates

i have a flask application backend(get) that returns a counter element(list). When submitting several times the same petition it keeps adding each element.

The flask get return should return only the values for this petition, not those stored in a sort of local memory. Devicedict1 contains for each id a list of fields:destination, origin, price of ticket sold, loyaltyProgram,etc.
Mydict8 contains for all records of each deviceid, all the tickets sold to this deviceID. for example mydict8[2][12]- contains origin station for this purchase, mydict8[3][12]- contains another origin station for this purchase-etc. I store the destination and origin station then in devicedict3, an return the top tuples(origin,destination) with Counter for each deviceid sent by a get request.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort
import csv
from flask import make_response
from collections import Counter
devicedict1 = collections.defaultdict(list)
devicedict3= collections.defaultdict(list)
mydict8 = []
with open('Salida1.csv', newline='', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    # rows1 = list(csv_reader)
    # print(len(rows1))
    line_count = 0
    count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        key = row[20]
        devicedict1[key].append(row)
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'El usuario no ha dado su permiso para dar su ID y por lo tanto esta vacio el ID'}), 404)
@app.errorhandler(401)
def not_found(error):
    return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'El formato del  ID es incorrecto'}), 401)   

@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/destinos/<string:destino>', methods=['GET'])
def get_destinos(destino):
count2 = len(devicedict1[destino])
            for i in range(0, count2):
                mydict8.append(devicedict1[destino][i])
            for i in range(0, len(mydict8)):
                devicedict3[i].append(mydict8[i][12])
                devicedict3[i].append( mydict8[i][13])
            n = 3
            return (str(Counter(map(tuple, devicedict3.values())).most_common(n)))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=50000, host='0.0.0.0')
```

So return should be the following when i do

```
curl -i http://10.3.4.38:50000/todo/api/v1.0/destinos/4ff70ad8e2e74f49
[(('3001', '1471'), 8), (('1471', '3001'), 5), (('3001', '1966'), 4)]
```

But I repeat this operation a second time and I get the following duplicates:

```
curl -i http://10.3.4.38:50000/todo/api/v1.0/destinos/4ff70ad8e2e74f49
[(('3001', '1471', '3001', '1471'), 8), (('3001', '1471'), 8), (('1471', '3001', '1471', '3001'), 5)]
```

I would like to receive the same answer each time I ask the server and in the second petition I am losing the third tuple of values:

```
('3001', '1966')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function you're append to the same, external lists each time:

```
for i in range(0, count2):
    mydict8.append(devicedict1[destino][i])

for i in range(0, len(mydict8)):
    devicedict3[i].append(mydict8[i][12])
    devicedict3[i].append( mydict8[i][13])
```

This will modify the global state of your application, which is not what you want. Instead initialize the lists inside your function and remove the outer initialization:

```
def get_destinos(destino):
    # this is the same as the for loop with range above
    mydict8 = devicedict1[destino][0:count2])
    devicedict3 = collections.defaultdict(list)
    ...
```

I'd probably pick better names than `mydict8` (which is a list...) and `devicedict3` as well, so they represent what they actually mean inside your function.